# How would I make an anti-sprite collision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Since my game's gonna involve sprites fighting each other I was thinking about adding something that basically stops them going through each other but I'm not sure as to how I can do it.

I have tried researching on this site if I could get a solution to my problem but so far I've found none

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without some context, but presumably you will want to start with looking at the existing collision functions like spritecollide or the slightly more specific collide_rect / collide_circle / collide_mask (depending on how complex your sprites are and how accurate you want collision detection to be)
( https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the pygame documentation and/or check some tutorials eventually. You'll run into a lot of problems. Writing a game can be frustrating, there is a lot of trial and error.
But to give you an idea of how it works, here is an example from a platformer I coded. I made minor adjustments such as `*.2` because it looked more natural this way:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
if hits:
    if player.rect.right < mob.rect.centerx-mob.rect.width*.2:
        player.rect.right = mob.rect.left
    elif player.rect.left > mob.rect.centerx+mob.rect.width*.2:
        player.rect.left = mob.rect.right
```